# App is running notification is displayed all the time

Tags: android, performance

I am building an android application that always shows the "App is running" notification, which leads to battery drain. If I force quit the app or turn off notification from settings, I stop receiving any other notifications.

Any help on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

the notification on android is displayed by calling the mNotificationManager.notify method (NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);  .  Try displaying your code to see